# jQuery Ajax unable to send PUT and DELETE REST API to ZF2 server

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, zend-framework2

I am having problem sending `PUT` and `DELETE` REST API from my front end to my ZF2 backend. However: I am able to send `POST` and `GET` request and it's working fine but not `PUT` and `DELETE` won't. Why?

Below is my ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        url: "/backend/api/product",
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data) {
                product= data.content;
            }
        }, error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseJSON.message);
        }
    });
```

The error that I get from my ZF2 are:

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template
>   "api/product/replace-list"; resolver could not resolve to a file

Comment: The error you're getting is because ZF2 can't find the view for `api/product/replace-list` which I feel is unrelated to the question you're asking. Please show what your controller action looks like and possibly your `view_manager` config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using restful controller with `JsonModel`. The restful controller will handle the restful requests `PUT` and `DELETE`. And the `JsonModel` will produce `JSON` output.

Here is a sample code that may help you,

```
use Zend\ViewModel\JsonModel;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;

class ProductController extends AbstractRestfulController
{    
    public function delete($id){

        // to handle delete 
        $responseData = new JsonModel(array(
            'key' => 'value'            
        ));

        return $responseData ;
    }

    public function update($id, $data){

        // to handle update
        $responseData = new JsonModel(array(
            'key' => 'value'            
        ));

        return $responseData ;
    }
}
```

Also in restful `PUT` method requires two params

1. ID (includes in url)
2. DATA (array)

so modify your ajax call as

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    url: "/backend/api/product/"+id,
    statusCode: {
        200: function (data) {
            product= data.content;
        }
    }, error: function (data) {
        alert(data.responseJSON.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: adding the "id" at the back of the ajax call url do the magic =) Thanks! You saved lot of my time!